# What is the command line to start appium 1.5.3 server programmatically in MAC?

Tags: java, ios, appium, saucelabs, appium-ios

For 1.4.3 the command was

**/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/bin/appium.js --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4723 --log-level debug**

but  in ver **1.5.3** "**appium.js**" is replaced with "**ios-webkit-debug-proxy-launcher.js**" and it stopped working .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node 
/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js
```